I'm getting an overflow error when trying to add a small string to a dbf
I'm copying information from some text files into a dbf file, which by the way has to be a dbf for work reasons, I've been storing data without much problems all things considered and all of a sudden i added a new value, here is a summary of my code without the surrounding code just so things can be understood more easily, and just assume that tipo_2 and tipo_3 are already well defined in previous steps
import dbf
DBF = dbf.Table('inp_rvi.dbf')
DBF.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
DBF.zap()
recno=0
for row in tipo_2:
    persons=int(row[2])
    for person in range(0,persons-1):
        recno += 1
        tupla = {'LLAVE':recno}
        #more code lived here and was removed as it 
        tupla['NOMBRE']=tipo_3[recno-1,3]
        
        i+=1
        DBF.append(tupla)


DBF.close()

the problem being that "NOMBRE" is supposed to store names but it throws at me an overflow error saying ('tried to store 35 bytes in 30 byte field',) I am rather stuck with this as I'm new to python. By the way the code fails when trying to store the dict "tupla" into "DBF", I used this variable "tupla" with many other entries and it is "nombres" the one that breaks it
I have tried looking at the source code but I still don't get why this error occurs, and other than this this is the closest I've been to solving this task I have tried using other ways to handle dbfs but all of them break at some point or another when trying to re-store the data back into a dbf, I cannot reduce the size of 'Nombres' as it was predefined in a DBF that I must work with. I can try other dbf libraries but I would much rather not have to.

If you can't change the table definition which restricts the NOMBRE field to 30 bytes nor shorten the value you want to store there can't be done anything.

I in fact can change the NOMBRE field in the DBF file to make it bigger (i just don't know how within python), i can't change the NOMBRE field of the source to make it smaller, which i know can cause confusion

Then you should just make the field big enough to store the data.

Then how to do so? I've tried to do so but I have not been able to find how yet

You wrote that you can make the field bigger. Do you want to know how to do this in Python? Is this the actual question?

Now that you mentioned it yes, it was not the original question but now that I know it's a possibility yes it is the question now I have looked for an answer but I have found nothing

DBF.resize_field('nombres', 35) -- @Micheal, you did the trouble-shooting, would you like to create the answer?

@MichaelButscher, you did the trouble-shooting, would you like to create the answer?

The field has a fixed maximum byte length. If you have to put more bytes into the field you have to change the table with DBF.resize_field('nombres', 35).
Code documentation of resize_field says:
resizes field (C only at this time)
creates backup file, then modifies current structure

